# How to see whether a Boolean function with different quantifiers is true given a quantifier as an example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

P(x,y) is a Boolean function, and∀x∃yP(x,y) is true and the domain is nonempty, then witch ones must also be true?

```
1.∀x∀yP(x,y)
2.∃x∀yP(x,y)
3.∃x∃yP(x,y)
```

Would anyone give me a hand on how to solve this problem? I had thought that I can simply make a Boolean function as an example but later realized that it would not cover all the cases. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Check that $p:\{0,1\}^2\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ defined by $p(1,0)=p(0,0)=1$ and $p(1,1)=p(0,1)=0$ satisfies the hypothesis but not 1, 2. As the domain is non-empty, there exists at least one pair $(x,y)$ in the domain, so it is straightforward  to see that $\forall x\,\exists y\,p(x,y)\Rightarrow  \exists x\,\exists y\,p(x,y)$ for all boolean functions, so only 3 must also be true.